# txt file character limit

Tags: python, webdriver, character, txt

I want my code to read from my txt file the line that have character limit of 280
If the line has more than 280 character it should skip the line

```
f = open('list.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8').readlines()
for word in f:
    if word == "\n":
        continue
driver.find_element_by_xpath(message_xpatch).send_keys(word)
```

Comment: I did try somethings like this `if not 0 < len(word) < 280`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length check should work if you put your driver statement inside the if statement:

```
f = open('list.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8').readlines()
for word in f:
    word = word.strip()
    if 0 < len(word) <280:
        print(word)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(message_xpatch).send_keys(word)
```